Only keeping medical terms in a block of text?
I downloaded this medical dictionary into R:
url <- "https://archive.org/stream/azfamilymedicalencyclopedia/A-Z%20Family%20Medical%20Encyclopedia_djvu.txt"
destfile <- "A-Z_Family_Medical_Encyclopedia.txt" # Save it locally with this name

download.file(url, destfile)

file_content <- readLines(destfile, encoding = "UTF-8")

Is it possible to only keep medical related terms and remove everything else?
I know how to remove stop words, e.g.
library(tm)

all_text <- paste(file_content, collapse = " ")

words <- unlist(strsplit(all_text, "\\W+"))

filtered_words <- words[!tolower(words) %in% stopwords("en")]

filtered_text <- paste(filtered_words, collapse = " ")

But is there something that can only keep things related to the medical/health? Ie. technical/scientific vocabluary?

You need to define what you mean by "medical/health" and "technical\scientific".  I think this is a case where the implementation is straightforward, but the definition is difficult and time consuming.  For example, is "bruise" a medical term, or do you want to keep only "haematoma"?  What about singular vs plural nouns?  Conjugated verbs?  Different tenses?

Hey user_436830 and welcome! It would be great if you could provide us with some motivation on what exactly you want to achieve with your question. This would help us to give more detailed advice on how to filter your original words.

@G-man: I am trying to help my friends that are ukrainian refugees develop a list of medical vocabulary they can translate into ukrainian and review. I am trying to find open sources of data for them.

You can obtain a list of medical terms here link.Then compare them with %in% just like you did before.
It will go something like this:
library(tm)
# set the current script's location as working directory
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))


url <- "https://archive.org/stream/azfamilymedicalencyclopedia/A-Z%20Family%20Medical%20Encyclopedia_djvu.txt"
destfile <- "A-Z_Family_Medical_Encyclopedia.txt" # Save it locally with this name

download.file(url, destfile)

file_content <- readLines(destfile, encoding = "UTF-8")

all_text <- paste(file_content, collapse = " ")

words <- unlist(strsplit(all_text, "\\W+"))

filtered_words <- words[!tolower(words) %in% stopwords("en")]

filtered_text <- paste(filtered_words, collapse = " ")

# URL for the medical terms word list
medical_terms_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glutanimate/wordlist-medicalterms-en/master/wordlist.txt"
medical_terms_file <- "medical_terms.txt"

# Download the medical terms list
download.file(medical_terms_url, medical_terms_file)

# Read the medical terms into a vector
medical_terms <- readLines(medical_terms_file, encoding = "UTF-8")
medical_terms <- tolower(medical_terms)  # Ensure all terms are in lowercase for matching


# Ensure all words in the text are in lowercase
filtered_words_lower <- tolower(filtered_words)

# Keep only words that are in the medical terms list
medical_filtered_words <- filtered_words_lower[filtered_words_lower %in% medical_terms]

unique_medical_filtered_words <-sort(unique(medical_filtered_words))

# do whatever you want with that :)

Results in 282.890 medical related words from 428.875 filtered_words, 10.950 of which being unique.

The issue with this is that the source is a medical encyclopaedia. If it was - for example - a person's medical records and you wished to find out which conditions they had then cross-referencing with a list of medical terms might be an approach (with a lot of false negatives). However, I'm not sure what you'd hope to achieve by comparing a list of medical terms to a medical encyclopaedia - unless you're trying to establish the comprehensiveness of the encyclopaedia itself.

@SamR Hmm you are right, maybe OP needs to learn a vocabulary list of medical terms provided in their source. So they want to filter out all not medical related words. But then I would even suggest to run a unique over medical_filtered_words
